# Find centre and radius of a circle

Tags: geometry

I have the question "Find the centre and radius of the circle whose equation is $x^2+y^2+x+3y-2=0$"

So I've worked out the centre to be $(-1/2, -3/2)$ which when I checked the solutions is correct however I got $9/2$ for the radius and in the solutions the radius should be $\frac{3\sqrt{2}}{2}$.

Could you explain how this is achieved for the radius?

Comment: Can you explain why you got 9/2?

Comment: So the equation is $(x+1/2)^2 + (y+3/2)^2 = 9/2 = 9/2$.  The equation of a circle is $(x-a)^2 + (y-b)^2 = r^2$ where $(a,b)$ is the center and $r$ its the radius.  So $9/2 = r^2$ so $r = \sqrt{9/2} = 3\sqrt{2}/2$.

Comment: It's okay I forgot to square root the radius haha.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You got $R^2$! you need $R$. So just take the square root.

Answer (score 1):

$x^2+y^2+x+3y-2=0 \Leftrightarrow (x+0.5)^2+(y+1.5)^2=4.5$

i suppose this is what you did. 
The common formula for circles is $(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2=r^2$ so you just need to take the root of $\frac{9}{2}$.

$\sqrt{\frac{9}{2}}=\frac{3}{\sqrt{2}}=3\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$